# Хранение токена андроид приложения. Yii2

Tags: java, android, yii2, firebase, push-уведомления

Надо хранить токены которые возвращаются с файрбейс на Yii2.

**Java**

```
 public class FirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
        @Override
        public void onTokenRefresh() {
            String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
            registerToken(token);
        }

        private void registerToken(String token) {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            RequestBody body = new FormBody.Builder()
                    .add("token",token)
                    .build();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("https://web-site.com/f/fcm")
                    .post(body)
                    .build();
            try {
                client.newCall(request).execute();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

**Yii2**

```
public function actionFcm()
{   
    $model = new Fcm();
    $request = Yii::$app->request;
    if($request->post('token'))
        {
            $token = $request->post('token');
            $model->token = $token;
            $model->save();
        }
    return $this->render('fcm', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

https://github.com/miskoajkula/Fcm/tree/Fcm/php_scripts  <--- оригинальный код PHP который хочу сделать на Yii2

Comment: https://web-site.com/f/fcm путь к экшену

Comment: А проблема-то в чем?

Comment: Eugene Krivenja проблема в том что в бд не сохраняется

Comment: А при чем тогда Java, Android, Firebase и push-уведомления? БД ведь на сервере. Вот с него и начинайте. Как только начнет сохранять, переходите к клиенту.